# Finding "islands" of territories on a map recursively

Tags: java, recursion

I have a map consisting of hexagonal fields. On this map every field(let's call it Hex) belongs to some player and is defined by coordinates.

**I need to get an `List<List<Hex>>` of a certain player's hexes. This means that if I input an array of all the hexes player owns, I need to get information about which ones are grouped together.**

Let me illustrate:

[image: Example of a hexagonal field owned by two players]

The input -> all hexes of green player -> `List<Hex> playersHexes` is:

> {0.0; 0.1; 0.2; 1.0; 1.3; 2.1; 2.3}

The output should be -> "islands" of green player:

> {0.0; 0.1; 0.2; 1.0} , {1.3; 2.3} , {2.1}

How can I achieve this recursively? I am able to find neighbours for some Hex without problems, but that's only for one iteration for a certain hex.

```
//playersHexes are all the hexes that a player owns
//map is the current map used - contains information about certain hexes
//map is not a HashMap! It's my custom object..
private void findIslands(List<Hex> playersHexes, Map map)
{
    List<Hex> island = new ArrayList<Hex>();
    int curPos = 0;
    for(Hex hex : playersHexes){
        island.add(hex);
        //remove the hex if it's allready gone through it?
        playersHexes.remove(curPos);
        List<Hex> neighbours = map.getNeighboursOf(hex);
        for(Hex neighbour : neighbours)
        {

        }
        //hexList is the output place - the target is to fill hexList with
        //islands(List<Hex>) of hexes..
        this.hexList.add(curPos, island);
        curPos++;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated - pseudo code with the working recursive function is sufficient.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my idea:

```
private void findIslands(List<Hex> playersHexes, Hex currentHex, Map map, List<Hex> island)
{
  List<Hex> neighbours = map.getNeighboursOf(currentHex);

  // for each neighbour we check if it belongs to player and if it is not already part of this island
  for(Hex neighbour : neighbours) {
     if (!island.contains(neighbour) && playersHexes.contains(neighbour))  {
        island.add(neighbour);

        // now find all connecting neighbours of the current neighbour
        findIslands(playersHexes, neighbour, map, island);
     }
  }
  // now we have in island all connecting Hexes of current hex
}
```

So this will find all connecting Hexes starting from one specific hex. All you need to do is create a while like this:

```
while (Player has hexes that are not islands yet) {
   // call findIsland() on one of those hexes and add the resulting list to your List<List<Hex>>
}
```

The actual implementation of that while you will figure out I'm sure ;)

Comment: Looks nice, I'll test it out, just a second. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Start with an empty list of islands (List of hexagons)
- **loop** through ordered list of hexagons belonging to a player:
- for each hexagon, **check** if it belongs to an existing island (adjacent to any of the islands hexagons)
- if yes: **add** it to the island
- if not: **create** a new island, consisting of that hexagon.

(Pseudo)Code (not tested):
*Note: using helper class Island for convenience (OO).*

```
class Island {

    private final List<Hex> hexes = new LinkedList<Hex>();

    public void add (Hex hex) {
        hexes.add(hex);
    }

    public List<Hex> getHexes () {
        return hexes;
    }

    public boolean isAdjacent (Hex hex) {
        for (Hex h : hexes) {
            if (h.isAdjacent(hex)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

private List<Island> createIslands (List<Hex> playersHexes,  Map map) {
    Collections.sort(playersHexes); // assuming it's comparable, otherwise use an iterator
    List<Island> islands=new LinkedList<Island>();
    for (Hex hex: playersHexes) {
        Island found=null;
        for (Island island: islands) {
            if (island.isAdjacent(hex)) {
                found=island;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found==null) {
            found=new Island();
            islands.add(found);
        }
        found.add(hex);
    }
    return islands;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! One more thing.. If it does belong to a certain island how do I get the island's index? And if it doesn't I just do `hexList.add(new ArrayList<List<Hex>>);` but how to add the current hex to the newly created island? Can you edit this info in, please?

Comment: This algorithm is not complete. Consider the one dimensional map `ABCDE`, where each letter represents one hex, and they are aligned in a straight line. Lets say hexes `B`, `C` and `D` belong to player 1. Assume we start "visiting" hex `B`, and thus we create the first island containing only `B`, so far. Then, we visit the hex `D`, conclude that it is not adjacent to `B` and hence we create a new island, containing only `D`. Then, we visit `C` and conclude it is adjacent to `B` so we add it to that island. Now we have **two islands**: one containing `B` and `D`, and one containing only `D`.

Comment: @Alderath: read again: I wrote to loop over the *ordered* list of hexagons, for exactly that reason.

Comment: @PeterWalser Looping in a well defined order is possible in the case of a one dimensional map, like in my example. In a two-dimensional case however, this is not possible. What order? It is impossible to have one order which works for all cases. One possible "ordered way" of iterating would be to loop through the x-coordinate first, and then the y coordinate. In the map the OP posted as an example, this would be: `0,0 -> 0,1 -> 0,2 -> 0,3 -> 1,0 -> 1,1 -> 1,2 -> 1,3 -> 2,0 -> 2,1 -> 2,2 -> 2,3`. This would create two islands if your algorithm was applied to the red player in the OP:s example.

Comment: @Alderath: you're right, I didn't see that. In that case, a merge sweep is necessary to merge islands if they have adjacent hexes.

Answer (score 1):

some scrappy pseudo code below, but this is how i would implement it

```
function main()
  get allIslands for the player
  for each island
    create islandGroup
    process(island, islandGroup, allIslands)



function process(island, islandGroup, allIslands)
  add this island  
  remove this island from the parent list
  getNeighbourIslands(island, allIslands)
  for each neighbourIsland
    process(neighbourIsland, islandGroup, allIslands)

function getNeighbourIslands(island, allIslands)
  return allIslands.getNeighbours(island)
```

by passing the allIslands list around, you can make sure you dont parse the same island twice, and don't get stuck in an infinite loop. when recursion finishes, you should end up with a load of IslandGroups

Edit: getNeighbourIslands, should return a list of the immediate neighbours to the island, you don't have to worry about their neighbours, they'll get scanned themselves later.

Comment: This looks like a correct answer, however I like Edgars approach more. +1 anyway - someone could prefer your answer.. Thanks!